# Setting up Ubuntu Server router in VM using Netplan, Shorewall and DNSMasq - unable to access internet from internal network

Tags: networking, ubuntu-18.04, shorewall

I'm currently creating network based on Ubuntu Server.

It's implemented as VM in VirtualBox and looks like this:

1. Ubuntu Server - 3 network interfaces. 1st - `enp0s3`, internet connection. 2rd - `enp0s9`, `room_two` - VBox internal network.
2. ArchLinux workstation - 1 network interface, `enp0s3`, connected to `room_two`.

What I want to achieve: **Server routing from `enp0s3` to `room_two` internal network.**

What I have done already:

```
# /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml

network:
ethernets:
    enp0s3:
        addresses: []
        dhcp4: true
    enp0s8:
        addresses: [192.168.1.1/16]
        dhcp4: false
version: 2
```

Shorewall setup for two interface router.

`/etc/shorewall/zones`

```
#ZONE   TYPE    OPTIONS                 IN                      OUT
#                                       OPTIONS                 OPTIONS
fw      firewall
net     ipv4
loc     ipv4
```

`/etc/shorewall/rules`

```
#ACTION         SOURCE          DEST            PROTO   DEST    SOURCE          ORIGINAL        RATE            USER/   MARK    CONNLIMIT       TIME            HEADERS         SWITCH          HELPER
#                                                       PORT    PORT(S)         DEST            LIMIT           GROUP
?SECTION ALL
?SECTION ESTABLISHED
?SECTION RELATED
?SECTION INVALID
?SECTION UNTRACKED
?SECTION NEW

#       Don't allow connection pickup from the net
#
Invalid(DROP)   net             all             tcp
#
#       Accept DNS connections from the firewall to the network
#
DNS(ACCEPT)     $FW             net
DNS(ACCEPT)     loc             $FW
#
#       Accept SSH connections from the local network for administration
#
SSH(ACCEPT)     loc             $FW
SSH(ACCEPT)     net             $FW
#
#       Allow Ping from the local network
#
Ping(ACCEPT)    loc             $FW
Ping(ACCEPT)    $FW             loc

#
# Drop Ping from the "bad" net zone.. and prevent your log from being flooded..
#

Ping(DROP)      net             $FW

ACCEPT          $FW             loc             icmp
ACCEPT          $FW             net             icmp
#
```

`/etc/shorewall/policy`

```
#SOURCE DEST            POLICY          LOGLEVEL        RATE    CONNLIMIT

$FW     net             ACCEPT
loc     net             ACCEPT
net     all             DROP            $LOG_LEVEL
# THE FOLOWING POLICY MUST BE LAST
all     all             REJECT          $LOG_LEVEL
```

`/etc/shorewall/interfaces`

```
#ZONE   INTERFACE       OPTIONS
net     NET_IF          dhcp,tcpflags,nosmurfs,routefilter,logmartians,sourceroute=0,physical=enp0s3
loc     LOC_IF          dhcp,tcpflags,nosmurfs,routefilter,logmartians,physical=enp0s8
```

`/etc/shorewall/snat`

```
# Rules generated from masq file /home/teastep/shorewall/trunk/Shorewall/Samples/two-interfaces/masq by Shorewall 5.0.13-RC1 - Sat Oct 15 11:41:40 PDT 2016
#
MASQUERADE              10.0.0.0/8,\
                        169.254.0.0/16,\
                        172.16.0.0/12,\
                        192.168.0.0/16          NET_IF
```

My Ubuntu Server works fine, DNS requests are cached and I can access internet. On my ArchLinux client I get an IP address from DHCP server and when I 'ping google.com' I get proper IP address but I get 100% packet loss. Where should I look for info and what kind? What may I have done wrong? There is not so many resources about Shorewall + Netplan setup as the latter is quite new.

Comment: I'd like to mention that both Ubuntu Server VM and Arch Linux VM can ping each other over internal network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, in `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

`net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`

Now everything works flawlessly!